# Confirm dialog from silverlight crashes firefox

Tags: javascript, silverlight, firefox3.6

I've found some strange behaviour of firefox 3.6 - when I call HtmlPage.Window.Confirm() method from my silverlight 3 app it crashes the browser. This behaviour, I think, begins from the version when plugin container became separate process. Maybe it is cross-thread issue of firefox.

Did anybody face this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "crush" exactly? If it's a real crash, can you reproduce it on another machine with the same OS and browser?

Comment: I expect it's all part of Microsoft's plot to crush Firefox...

Comment: I think "crush" means that Firefox is in love with Silverlight - which sounds strange? ;-)

Comment: It's not actualy the crash :), but browser's not responding until I kill it from the processes. On the same OS - the same behaviour.

Comment: same issue for me, does anyone have a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I had the same problem with Firefox but you should be able to get around it by using Silverlight's MessageBox command with the optional MessageBoxButton.OKCancel flag.

```
MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting param windowless to true in most cases helps to fix this problem.